# Domain redirection to TCP applications with different ports but to the same IP

Tags: nginx, proxy, dns

The question is the following, if possible through nginx or similar, redirect a domain to connect to an internal port located on the same computer eg:

```
domainnametest.com => 83.12.a.b:4000 (http or anyelse)
application 1 listening on: 83.12.a.b:4001
application 2 listening on: 83.12.a.b:4002
```

Then that from a client make a request of the type:

```
"application1.nombredominiotest.com:4000" -> redirect to application 1 on "83.12.a.b:4001"
```

o

```
"application2.nombredominiotest.com:4000" -> redirect to application 2 on "83.12.a.b:4002"
```

**NOTE**: 
- Always using domainnametest:4000 as a bridge since 4000 is the only open port.
- Application 1 and Application 2 are not equals.

**EDIT:**

[image: Deployment Model]

Thanks!

**EDIT 2:** The problem Is resolved with this configuration in nginx:

```
stream { 
    upstream stream_backend { 
        server app1.com:4001; 
        server app2.com:4002; 
    } 
    server { 
        listen 4000; 
        proxy_pass stream_backend; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use nginx as a reverse proxy to  load balance traffic from port `4000` over ports `4001,4002`:

```
stream {
    upstream application {
        server 127.0.0.1:4001
        server 127.0.0.1:4002
    }
    server {
        listen 4000
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass application; 
    }
}
```

https://www.nginx.com/blog/tcp-load-balancing-udp-load-balancing-nginx-tips-tricks/

#### EDIT

Now that you added the chart I see that you need nginx to redirect each app to its own port, and that can be done with nginx name-based routing

```
server {
    listen 4000;
    server_name app1.com; # <-- app1 name
        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4001; # <-- app1 port
        }
}
server {
    listen 4000;
    server_name app2.com; # <-- app2 name
        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4002; # <-- app2 port
        }
}
```

http://blog.manugarri.com/how-to-easily-set-up-subdomain-routing-in-nginx/

dont forget to redirect hosts on your `/etc/hosts` file:

```
<nginx_server_ip>   app1.com app2.com
```

if you need it to be publicly accessible you will have to associate your nginx server with a dns record [how](https://www.ntchosting.com/encyclopedia/dns/registration/)

#### EDIT 2

```
stream { 
    upstream stream_backend { 
        server app1.com:4001; 
        server app2.com:4002; 
    } 
    server { 
        listen 4000; 
        proxy_pass stream_backend; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Doen't work it aproach because application 1 is no equals to application 2, I don't know if nginx could do it

Comment: @JuanPablo can you provide more details about your infrastructure? in English/ make a chart https://www.draw.io/

Comment: I have created a diagram, I don't know if you understand more now, Thanks

Comment: Hi, could you update your response with this configuration to validate response, 

stream {
 upstream stream_backend {
  server app1.com:4001;
  server app2.com:4002;
 }
 
 server {
  listen 4000;
  proxy_pass stream_backend;
 }

}

Thanks